# Remove element in dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am working on Python code to remove certain elements in dictionary of lists.

```
dict ={'s': ['a','b'],'d': ['c','d'],'g': ['e','f']}
values = ['a','c','f']

list2 ={i:j.remove(value) for i,j in dict.items() for k in j for value in values if value in k}

print(list2)
```

Below code is working giving expected result. I am facing issue with comprehensions(above mentioned code)

```
for i,j in dict.items():

    for k in j:

        for value in values:

            if value in k:

                j.remove(value)
```

I am not sure why comprehension is not working. Please help me with efficient way of solving this

Actual Result:

```
{'s': None, 'd': None, 'g': None}
```

Expected Result:

```
{'s': ['b'], 'd': ['d'], 'g': ['e']}
```

Comment: `j.remove` returns `None`, it is an in-place function, which is why your dict is filled with `None`

Comment: The nested code loop can't work either, because removing elements from a list you are iterating over will cause issues.

Comment: Is there is efficient way of doing this?

Comment: `remove` returns `None`. . Also never use `dict` to name a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to mutate a list mid-iteration, just do membership checks in `values` by iterating over the members of `j`:

```py
d ={'s': ['a','b'],'d': ['c','d'],'g': ['e','f']}
values = ['a','c','f']

list2 ={i: [a for a in j if a not in values] for i,j in d.items()}

print(list2)
{'s': ['b'], 'd': ['d'], 'g': ['e']}
```

As a side-note, I've also removed the `dict` variable name because it shadows a built-in. This is definitely something to avoid because you can run into some iffy behavior later:

```py
dict = {'a': 1}

d = dict([('b',2), ('c',3)])

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rename your dict variable to something other than `dict`:

```
d = {'s': ['a','b'],'d': ['c','d'],'g': ['e','f']}
values = ['a','c','f']
```

Just use list comprehension to get the items in each list that aren't in `values`:

```
d2 = {k:[i for i in v if i not in values] for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip()`:

**For understanding**:

```
dict_ ={'s': ['a','b'],'d': ['c','d'],'g': ['e','f']}
values = ['a','c','f']

for (k,v), elem  in zip(dict_.items(), values):
    if elem in v:
        v.remove(elem)
print(dict_)
```

Using `dict-comprehension`:

Think of it like:

*If **element** of the list **values** is **not in** the list **value** of **key** in **dict_***

```
print({k:v for (k,v), elem  in zip(dict.items(), values) if elem not in v })
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'s': ['b'], 'd': ['d'], 'g': ['e']}
```